# Openldap: is possible to delete this entry?

Tags: openldap

I have created this entry

```
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 2c768a98
dn: cn=module{2}
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{2}
olcModulePath: /usr/lib64/openldap
olcModuleLoad: {0}back_monitor
structuralObjectClass: olcModuleList
entryUUID: 343d1582-20cf-103e-9530-cb5015b84c6f
creatorsName: cn=ldapadm,dc=ldap1,dc=my,dc=my
createTimestamp: 20231126174433Z
entryCSN: 20231126174433.779813Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=ldapadm,dc=ldap1,dc=my,dc=my
modifyTimestamp: 20231126174433Z
```

Now I want to delete it.
A dirty way is to remove the file (!) and restart slapd
But I want to know if is possible to remove with ldapmodify
so I don't have to restart slapd.